# Binding Class to Material-Table data in React

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Is it possible to pass an object directly to Material-table data?
I have no issues if I define my data using the fields directly, e.g.

`const [data, setData] = useState([{id:'id', name:'name', description:'description', base_price:'10'}]);`

but get an error from react if I try to use an object class.

`const [data, setData] = useState([new ProductImpl(1, "productName", "description of product", 12.50, new Date(), 1)]);`

where this class has the same fields as the material table is looking for:

```
export class ProductImpl implements Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    base_price: number;
    posted_date: Date;
    category_id: number;

    constructor (
        id: number,
        name: string,
        description: string, 
        base_price:number, 
        posted_date: Date,
        category_id: number) 
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.base_price = base_price;
            this.posted_date = posted_date;
            this.category_id = category_id;
        }
}
```

```
const ProductTable = (): JSX.Element => {


    const columns = [
        { title: "Id", field: "id" },
        { title: "name", field: "name" },
        { title: "description", field: "description" },
        { title: "base_price", field: "base_price" },
        { title: "posted_date", field: "posted_date" },
        { title: "category_id", field: "category_id" },
    ];

    const [data, setData] = useState([{id:'id', name:'name', description:'description', base_price:'10'}]);
        return (
        <div className="ProductTable">         
           <MaterialTable
             title="Products"
             columns={columns}
             data={data}
           />
        </div>
        );
};
  
  export default ProductTable;
```

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: `{}` is an object, so you are passing an object. If you mean pass a class, what is the benefit of doing so?

If you are using the class elsewhere you can use a solution like this `const {...object} = classInstance` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699529/convert-javascript-class-instance-to-plain-object-preserving-methods

Comment: Thanks @talfreds . The idea here is I'll be getting data back from server in this class structure. I just want to pass through and display in simple table :/

Comment: `const {...object} = classInstance` should solve the problem then? where object is the value for the `data` prop