# How to return the correct object in JS OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, tdd

My program is returning the wrong kind of object. My console.logs always seem to find what i create but im either returning it wrong or my tests are set up wrong. Could anyone help me?
So im building a very basic multi page multi class program. styled like a game. Use OOP and TDD. All my test fail and claim i am returning the wrong type of object. for example
`Expected object to be a kind of Object, but was Character({ characterName: 'Dr Alan Grant', characterAge: 42, health: 100, invintory: [  ], weapons: [  ] }).`
or     `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

It seems to be the same error so it must really be one simple thing im not quite getting about building using classes and multiple classes. I have tried googling it but had very little luck. I know the code is a little long. But its the same issue throughtout so if you fix one you fix them all i guess.

````js
onst Character = require('../src/character')

class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.characters = []
    }

    createCharacter(characterName, characterAge) {
        const character = new Character(characterName, characterAge)
        this.characters.push(character)
        console.log('char = ', character)
        return this.characters[0]
    }
    
    findCharacter(searchName) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.characters.length; i++) {
            /// which way to i look character or characters
            if (this.characters[i].characterName === searchName) {
                return this.characters[i]
            } else {
                return 'Error! Character not found!'
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    showAllCharacters() {
        return this.characters
    }

    deleteCharacter(searchName) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.characters.length; i++) {
            if (this.character[i].characterName === searchName) {
                this.characters.splice(this.characters[i], 1)
                return 'Player deleted'
            } else {
                return 'Player Not Found'
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Game
class Character {
    constructor(characterName, characterAge) {
        this.characterName = characterName
        this.characterAge = characterAge
        this.health = 100
        this.invintory = []
        this.weapons = []
    }
}
module.exports = Character

const Character = require('../src/character')
// const Attackers = require('../src/attackers')
const Game = require('../src/Game')

describe('Jurrasic World ', () => {
    let character
    beforeEach(function () {
    character = new Character()
  })
  //  let attackers
  //   beforeEach(function () {
  //   attackers = new Attackers()
  // })
  let game
    beforeEach(function () {
    game = new Game()
  })

  it('create a new character', () => {
    // set up
    const expectedResult = {
      characterName: 'Dr Alan Grant',
      characterAge: 42,
      health: 100,
      invintory: [],
      weapons: []
    }
    // execute
    const result = game.createCharacter('Dr Alan Grant', 42)
    // verifty
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult)
  })
it('delete character by name', () => {
    // set up 
    const expectedResult = 'Player deleted'
    // execute
    game.createCharacter('Dr Alan Grant', 42)
    const result = game.deleteCharacter('Dr Alan Grant')
    // verify
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult)
    // expect(game.characters).toEqual([])
  })
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Note: `createCharacter` always returns the first character.
As for the error messsage, It seems to be comparing the result to an object where as it should be a class instance type Character which is apparently different. Try this
`const {...object} = classInstance` to convert to type object.

```js
class Character {
  constructor(characterName, characterAge) {
    this.characterName = characterName
    this.characterAge = characterAge
    this.health = 100
    this.invintory = []
    this.weapons = []
  }
}

var instance = new Character("Jack", 80)
var { ...obj } = instance;

// but they do look the same
console.log(instance)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. i made the last line of createCharacter         ```return {...character}```
and it seems to pass the tests...im not sure why. Whats that called so i can read up on it?

Comment: spread syntax and de-structuring  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66774294/3807365)

Comment: You don't need to `return {...character}` from `createCharacter ` because it will convert to object. You want to do the conversion only for testing purposes.

Comment: is this right. it seems to work ```createCharacter(characterName, characterAge) {
        const { ...obj } = new Character(characterName, characterAge)
        this.characters.push({ ...obj })
        console.log('char = ', { ...obj })
        console.log('characters array = ', this.characters)
        return { ...obj }
    }```

Comment: You can think of `{...obj} = instance` as cloning the object. Once you cloned the instance to `obj` (why do you?) you can continue with using `obj` no need to clone again and again

Comment: Ok so i want my original `` const char = new char('name)``` then below that clone it as just a returnable object? ```let {...obj} = char``` and then return that?

Comment: I wouldn't touch the program and leave it as `Character` instance. It is only for *testing* that I would clone it to object so I could compare it to the expected value.